What is this diode marked IN4001 B4?
the information on the diode reads as either:
IN4001
B4
OR
1N4001
B4
I am trying to purchase a replacement diode and the only close matches I can find make no reference to the B4 element. Is this part of the identification important? If so, what does it mean and where can I find somewhere that stocks it?
Any information would be great

B4 is probably a lot code or something of that ilk.
Just replace it with a 1N400x where x = 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7.
If you buy some of the higher numbers you can use them to replace any lower number ('7' = 1kV PIV, '1' = 50V PIV rating). Cost difference is usually negligible.

Incidentally, most rectifiers break down well over 600V anyway; the series has lost all meaning. Manufacturers fill x=1-4 with the same (4 or 5) part, and the rest with 7. Or all with 7. What you're actually buying in a 1N4001 is the possibility that it breaks down at such a low rating. At least -- I haven't measured a new one anywhere near that low; but that's not to say you'll never find one that does.

It is a generic general-purpose diode. B4 does not mean anything except to the manufacturer. Look for any diode with a 1-amp forward current or greater and a 50-volt peak repetitive reverse voltage or greater. Nothing special about any diode will work. Some alternatives to consider are 1N4148, 1N4733, 1N5408, and 1N5822.

I wouldn't suggest any of those as an alternative, 1N4148 is a 200 mA diode, 1N4733 is a 5.1V Zener diode, 1N5408 is a 3A 1000V diode (overkill), and 1N5822 is a 3A 48V Schottky diode.
